# Абсолютный путь... Картинки и файлы в браузере

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, возникла следующая задача...

На локальном компьютере стоит OpenServer из под которого работает сайт...
В различные разделы сайта необходимо подключать картинки или файлы для скачивания...
Все ничего если папка с картинками|файлами лежит в корне сайта или глубже (используются локальные пути... тут все хорошо), но что делать если путь будет вне сервера, скажем на диске C:\images или на подключаемом съемном носителе...
код вида 
по соображению безопасности не проходит...
Как полноценно в таком случае выводить картинки на страничках и ссылки на файлы для скачивания?

Comment: а почему ваши файлы должны находиться вне сервера ?! Вы же сайт делаете для интернета.... причём тут "подключаемом съемном носителе" ??

Comment: ../ — вот такая конструкция помогает спускаться вниз по дереву. Можно вот так: ../../ ну и еще глубже сколько нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но сайт делается не для интернета а для локалки... а подключаемые файлы не могут находится в корневой... соответственно решение с ../ и тд не подходит... Решение нашел следующее, для отображения картинок получаю файл через file_get_content, далее вывожу его через img src base64_encode (работает как для путей с левым так и правым слешем, при условии что левый слеш в случае путей windows нужно дублировать) в случае с файлами, отдаю их через скрипт... пример кода можно найти в интернет...

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про Linux, то этот вопрос решается достаточно просто. Монтируете нужный диск или носитель в директорию, в которой лежат файлы вашего сайта, а далее указываете путь уже относительно смонтированной директории.